# transparent navigation bar swift не срабатывает на iphone X?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, navigationbar

С толкнулся с проблемой картинка не до конца до упора доходит в transparent navigation bar на симуляторе iphone X?Именно половину статус бара закрывает.В файле Info.plist все прописано.Метод прописан в  viewDidLoad().Пожалуйста помогите? Я уже сделал отдельным проектом и не срабатывает.Есть профи чтоб подсказать где я допустил ошибку.И еще решились помочь и ответили мне, пожалуйста проверяйте комментарии.Я каждые 2-3 часа всегда захожу и жду ответа.

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Прикрепляю скрины крепления.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я вижу корневым элементом внутри главного `UIView` вашего `UIViewController` является `UITableView`, об этом Вы забыли упомянуть, хотя следовало бы. То есть для начала надо проверить, правильно ли Вы растянули данную таблицу. По умолчанию даже если верх Вашей таблицы прикреплён к верху корневого `UIView` у Вас всё-равно будет отступ сверху (данное поведение появилось лишь в iOS11). Убрать его можно вот так:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

    self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}
```

И тогда Ваша таблица (вместе с картинкой в её ячейке) будет растянута до самого верха.

То же самое можно сделать и через файл с разметкой. В настройках `UITableView` найдите раздел "Scroll View", где у параметра "Content Insets" установите значение "Never". Для наглядности можете изучить следующий снимок экрана (необходимый параметр обозначен стрелкой):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и еще раз за помощь))! Да я уже нашел именно это и сделал.Только использовал код, теперь буду знать и можно без кода обойтись.